# Should local HDFS access be faster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running HDFS (0.20.2) on some aws-instances. I forced HDFS to write all blocks of a file to one datanode (By reducing the replication to 1 and only adding 1 datanode).

I don't see any significant performance difference when accessing the file locally (on the datanode the blocks are stored on) or from another host in my cluster. Essentially the time it takes to perform a copyToLocal is exactly the same wether I am on the local-datanode or on any other machine (The same thing holds for accessing through the JAVA-API)
Shouldn't there be a difference?

The file has a size of 3.5 GB and the block size is 128MB (If this does matter). The instances where normal medium instances.

**Update**

Thx for your suggestions but the actual problem only occurs on the small or medium instances while on large instances I get the expected behavior (So local access is significantly faster ~20s vs ~40s).

Comment: 1. The client running the copyToLocal command is once on the datanode where the data resides and then on another machine ?
2. The namenode is on the same machine ?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. No the namenode is on a different machine that has no datanodes

Comment: Since you have only one datanode, the replica placement strategy doesn't make any difference. 
As a side note, can you tell us the times you get in the 2 cases.

Comment: Well, running copyToLocal I got ~1:30 for both local and remote client.Please note that all machines are in one availability zone.

I also run a hadoop fs -cat > /dev/null which ran in 38seconds on both the local and remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I understand the question but you might be interested in [HDFS-2246](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2246) which speeds up reads when blocks are local to the data node. It is also mentioned in the [1.0.0 release notes](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/releasenotes.html) and in this [HBaseCon 2012 presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/1-todd-lipcon-past-present-futurepdf).